# Float error when inserting table

Tags: tables, floats, shading

I am admittedly a complete novice when it comes to using Latex but I'm really enjoying its practicality when it comes to note taking in science and math courses. However I am now trying to insert a table into a shaded region but receive an error that says"!LaTeX Error:Float(s) lost."

Would someone please explain to me what is wrong with my coding. Originally I had created a table, but thinking I had done a typo I googled a table from a tutorial and pasted it in and still receive the error.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength{\tabcont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!15}
\parindent 0in
\parskip 12pt
\geometry{margin=1in, headsep=0.25in}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{reg}{Rule}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{note}{Note}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\title{Lecture 9 Notes}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE \bf Lecture 9}\\
\section{Chemical Equilibrium - Chapter 6}
\subsection{Calculating Equilibrium Constant}
\begin{shaded}
\textbf{Example 4}\\
In order to study hydrogen halide decomposition, a researcher fills an evacuated 2.00L flask with 0.200mol of $HI$ gas and allows the reaction to proceed at 453$\degree$C.\\
At equilibrium, $[HI]=0.078$mol. Calculate $K_c$.\\
$2HI(g)\rightleftharpoons H_2(g)+I_2(g)$\\
First we need to convert mol to concentration: $[HI]=\frac{0.200mol}{2.00L}=0.100M$
Now we need to use an ICE table:
\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Your first table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
      \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
      $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
      \hline
      1 & 1110.1 & a\\
      2 & 10.1 & b\\
      3 & 23.113231 & c\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{shaded}



\end{document}
```

Comment: (i)  float `table` (`figure` etc ) had not to be enclosed in other environments like `minipage, `shade` etc. (ii) your code is not compilable, you have errors in determining of `center`, (iii) do you really need so many packages? (iv) it is sufficient to load each package only ones, ... welcome to tex.se!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[H]` option from `float`, which makes the table not float (however, this may produce large white spaces) or replace the `table` environment + `\vation` with `center +`\captionof[table{...}`.

I loaded the `caption` package to have a sensible spacing between caption and  table, `titlesec`  with option `[center]`to avoid typing all those `center` environments, `siunitx` to have a correct spacing when typing units.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs, caption, float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{cancel}
%\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newlength{\tabcont}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!15}
\parindent 0in
\parskip 12pt
\geometry{margin=1in, headsep=0.25in}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{reg}{Rule}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}
\newtheorem{note}{Note}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\title{Lecture 9 Notes}

\thispagestyle{empty}

{\LARGE \bfseries Lecture 9}\\
\section{Chemical Equilibrium – Chapter 6}
\subsection{Calculating Equilibrium Constant}
\begin{shaded}
\leavevmode\centerline{\textbf{Example 4}}
In order to study hydrogen halide decomposition, a researcher fills an evacuated \SI{2.00}{\L} flask with \SI{0.200}{\mol } of $HI$ gas and allows the reaction to proceed at \SI{453}{\celsius}.\\
At equilibrium, $[HI]=\SI{0.078}{\mol}$. Calculate $K_c$.\\
$2HI(g)\rightleftharpoons H_2(g)+I_2(g)$\\
First we need to convert mol to concentration: $[HI]=\mfrac{\SI{0.200}{\mol}}{2.00L}=\SI{0.100}{M}$.
Now we need to use an ICE table:
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
    \caption{Your first table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
      \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
      $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
      \hline
      1 & 1110.1 & a\\
      2 & 10.1 & b\\
      3 & 23.113231 & c\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{shaded}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! That's exactly what I wanted!!